# Best way to separate two strings from a variable

Tags: php, string, variables

I have managed to retrieve the data I'm looking for which is in the form of two urls and I need to extract them into two separate variables. Am I retrieving the data the most efficient way and how can I then have two variables containing the url data.

```
$item = $this->_item;//Item ID

foreach ($item->getElements() as $elements) {
    $images = $elements->get('file');

    if(!empty($images)) {
        $imagesnonnull = $images;
        $image = JURI::base() . $imagesnonnull;
        var_dump($image);
    }
}
```

The var_dump result is below:

```
string(33) "http://demo.com/images/image1.jpg"
string(33) "http://demo.com/images/image2.jpg"
```

I happy to provide more info and try any suggestions to improve the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

1- array

```
$image[] = JURI::base() . $imagesnonnull;
```

2- or String

```
$image.= JURI::base() . $imagesnonnull;
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response and for giving me a couple of options. Looking at it now it was a simple solution thanks to both yourself and Mike for not making me feel silly for asking it.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I then have two variables containing the url data.

By pushing them onto an array

```
$urls[] = $url;
```

Comment: Thanks for you quick response and a very easy answer too

Answer (score 0):

```
 $item = $this->_item;//Item ID
 $urls = array();

            foreach ($item->getElements() as $elements) {
                $images = $elements->get('file');

                   if(!empty($images)) {
                       $imagesnonnull = $images;
                       $image = JURI::base() . $imagesnonnull;
                       //var_dump($image);
                       $urls[] = $image;
                   }
            }
```

get array values afterwards