# Separate two string items in a variable for retrival and separate display

Tags: javascript

I have a query that returns a name and a URL. I loop through my result and print out each line. I am struggling to assign the URL to the href field. I can make this work if I only return the URL in the query.

However I am pulling a blank then trying to query the name and URL and then assign the URL to the href and the name to the text field from the query array results. I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748527/best-way-to-seperate-two-strings-from-a-variable), however I am unsure how to proceed.

```
var Results = (Fish(Query).select("LATINNAME","URL"));

var outputc = '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';
for (LATINNAME in Results) {
    outputc += ' <li><a href="'+URL+'">' + Results[LATINNAME] + '</a></li> ';
}
outputc += '</ul>';
```

**I can make the URL work if I only output it into my variable by removing the latinname from the query**

```
     outputc += ' <li><a href="'+  Results[LATINNAME]+'">' + '</a></li> ';
```

**Array output for results**

```
[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]
0: Array[2]
0: "Acipenseridae"
1: "Endpoints1.html"
length: 2

1: Array[2]
0: "Cottidae"
1: "Endpoints2.html"
length: 2

2: Array[2]
0: "Gadidae"
1: "Endpoints3.html"
length: 2
```

**Output C - Currently I am just adding the URL as a string to print it out**

```
 <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
  <li><a href="function URL() { [native code] }">Acipenseridae,Endpoints.html</a></li>
  <li><a href="function URL() { [native code] }">Cottidae,Endpoints.html</a></li> 
  <li><a href="function URL() { [native code] }">Gadidae,Endpoints.html</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post your array of results as a string?

Comment: @IvanSeidel I have posted the console output for Results. I know in php I would need to use [0] and [1] to place the different array elements. Obviously +URL+ is wrong but this is where im not sure.

Comment: can you post the `outputc` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting your results correctly. In fact, since I don't like your raw HTML strings, I'm going to do this with DOM methods :p

```
var Results = Fish(Query).select("LATINNAME","URL");
var output = document.createElement('ul');
output.setAttribute("data-role","listview");
output.setAttribute("data-inset","true");
var l = Results.length, i, link;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    link = output.appendChild(document.createElement('li'))
                              .appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
    link.href = Results[i][1];
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Results[i][0]));
    // hey! built-in anti-XSS!
}
// find somewhere and .appendChild(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having trouble with finding the value in the Array(of Arrays).

If you look at the `Results`, you will see that you are not dealing with a 1D array, instead with a 2D array. The proper code to do so is like this:

```
var LATINNAME = 1; // Key where it is allocated (just to help)
var Results = (Fish(Query).select("LATINNAME","URL"));

var outputc = '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';
for (var k in Results) {
    var result = Results[k];
    outputc += ' <li><a href="'+URL+'">' + result[LATINNAME] + '</a></li> ';
}
outputc += '</ul>';
```

Notice that you CANNOT access a hash key like this: `Results[LATINNAME]` IF you didn't declared LATINNAME variable value (in this case, it's acting as a variable). You would instead, if the key LATINNAME existed, use: `Results.LATINNAME`, but it's stored in the key `1` as you can see in your log.